# Tweaking zsh git autocompletion

Tags: git, zsh

I just switched from bash to using zsh 4.3.4 on Ubuntu Hardy.  I'm developing with git and I find myself constantly fighting with the default git completions: filename completion tries to be smart by detecting what you've added or removed (using git-ls-files) but sometimes it gets things wrong---e.g., if you are in a sub-directory.  It also doesn't know about my custom git aliases (e.g., git ci as an alias for commit).

zsh superusers, how should I improve this situation?

Here are some of my thoughts, though I don't know how to implement them as I'm new to zsh, so maybe you can help or offer your own:

- Disable git filename completion, leaving just branch/tag/command-name/command-option completion.
- Replace the "smart" filename completion with the regular zsh filename completion.
- Get a newer _git completion file, if it fixes these bugs, and override the system one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried http://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, it just adds a git prompt and doesn't tweak the underlying completions.

Comment: Can someone just tell us how to disable all the "smart" completion for all git commands?  They do too much IO. The shell needs to respond instantly.  I just want to go back to good old simple filename completion for git commands.  Every time I do a web search for this I just get a maze of generic zsh man page info.

Comment: FYI for anyone who wants to just disable the annoying git completion that causes the shell to block doing IO, on Ubuntu 10.04, I just did this:

`sudo mv /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/OFF_git`

Answer (score 6):

For large projects, even the newer git completion scripts are far too slow. To disable them and just use normal file completion, place the following command in your .zshrc:

```
compdef -d git
```

Answer (score 5):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Zsh. I just upgraded from 4.3.4 to 4.3.10 and it at least fixes the problem with Git aliases not completing.

Instead of hacking my installation I added this to my local `.zshrc`:

```
customzsh=/usr/local/src/zsh-4.3.10/bin/zsh-4.3.10
if [ "$SHELL" != "$customzsh" ]; then
  export SHELL=$customzsh
  exec $customzsh
fi
```